# Apache .htaccess rewrite multiple condition with parameters by subdomain

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I currently have this in my .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*).domain\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?id=%1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

All my subdomain regardless is abc.domain.com or def.domain.com will be pointing towards index.php?id=abc and index.php?id=def respectively.

This is currently working perfectly fine on my website however I have other file path like domain.com/faq.php, Hence when user access abc.domain.com/faq.php , this will be pointing to faq.php?id=abc as well.

So my question is how to capture the file path parameter and rewrite with the parameter being pass?

Thank you for the help and please let me know if you require any other information. I'm currently new to rewrite mod hence, this might be a duplicate question.

Comment: I guess this should read "Hence when user access abc.domain.com/faq.php , this will be pointing to *index*.php?id=abc as well."

Answer (score 0):

You can try this rules:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*).domain\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*\.php)$ $1?id=%1 [L,NC,QSA]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*).domain\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?id=%1 [L,NC,QSA]
```